# How to integrate the following: $\int{\frac{2y'y}{y^2+1}dx}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have encountered the following problem:

> $$\int{\frac{2y'y}{y^2+1}dx}$$

According to wolfram the solution is: $\log(y^2 + 1)$.
How was this solution derived and which rules were used?

Comment: This comes from the chain rule and the derivative of log.

Comment: You have a $y'$ so it looks like you were trying to solve a differential equation. The solution from WolframAlpha is not the solution to that differential equation; rather it is the antiderivative of $\frac{2y}{1+y^2}$. The solution of the differential equation would be found by writing $\int \frac{2y}{1+y^2}dy=\int dx$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int { \frac { 2y }{ y^{ 2 }+1 } dy=\int { \frac { d\left( y^{ 2 }+1 \right)  }{ y^{ 2 }+1 }  } =\ln { \left( y^{ 2 }+1 \right) +C }  } $$
or substitute $\theta =y^{ 2 }+1\\ d\theta =2ydy$
$$\int { \frac { 2y }{ y^{ 2 }+1 } dy=\int { \frac { d\theta  }{ \theta  }  }  } =\ln { \theta +C=\ln { \left( y^{ 2 }+1 \right) +C }  } $$

Answer (score 1):

As it is mentioned in the comments, it is a consequence of the so called **logarithmic derivate**:

> $$\frac{d}{dx}\log(f(x))=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$

applied to the special case of $$f(x):=y^2(x)+1,$$
and of course, in the last step, to the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$\int f'=f+c.$$

Answer (score 0):

You have a $y'$ so it looks like you were trying to solve the differential 
equation.

$$2y\frac{dy}{dx}=1+y^2$$

The solution from WolframAlpha is not the solution to that differential equation; rather it is the antiderivative of $\frac{2y}{1+y^2}$. The solution of the differential equation would be found by writing

$$\int \frac{2y}{1+y^2}dy=\int dx.$$

The integration gives $$\ln(1+y^2)=x+c$$

so that

$$1+y^2=e^{x+c}$$

or

$$y=\pm\sqrt{e^{x+c}-1}$$

(where we require $x\geq-c$.)

Comment: You just assumed that the integrand is equal to 1, which was not mentioned by the OP...

Comment: Yes, because I inferred that he had gone from $2y\frac{dy}{dx}=1+y^2$ to $\int\frac{2(dy/dx)y}{1+y^2}$. Otherwise, what is the $y'$?  I simply assumed the integrand was equal to one, because that was the most likely. Of course I may be wrong.

Comment: If OP just wanted the derivative of $\log (1+y(x))$, then that is explained in another answer.